# User permission Problem for workflows in wss-3.0

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, wss-3.0

Im running wss-3.0 on a Windows Server 2003 machine. The User Accounts are AD based.

I made a Calendar List with 3 different Permission Groups.

1. Users that can only read the list
2. Users that can add new Items and edit only the items they added themselves
3. Users that can edit/delete all items.

I created a SPD workflow for that list which should fire an email to all Persons named in a Persons/Group column everytime a item is created. This works without problems for Users in Group 3. But for Users in Group 2 nothing happens after the item is created. The Workflow history shows me an "Access Denied" error for that workflow everytime a group 2 user creates an item.

After seeing the error message, i tried upgrading group 2 to "Contibute" Permission level. It worked, emails are being sent. But the problem is, that the users in group 2 should not be able to edit/delete the listitems other people created.

The workflow history shows that the user for the workflow that got the "Access Denied" was the System Account which should have enough permissions.

Is there any way of not giving users "Contribute" permissions and still let workflows activate when those users create a new item on this list?

Comment: question is where exactly it got Access Denied, while sending email or while getting user's data, can you post some code or do some attached debugging :)

Comment: We got a little closer to the problem. Sending the mails doesnt seem to be the problem but in the same step, we update a field of that element. Thats what got us the Access Denied, not the email-sending. The workflow is: new element -> send email -> edit field.
But we still dont understand why we get Access Denied because the user has the permissions to edit the elements he has created and the System Account has admin permissions

Comment: How exactly did you restricted for group 2 to allow them to edit only their own itens? You did it changing it into the list advanced properties? So, if you did it once in the list properties, how did you allowed group 3 to edit every other item? With Design/Full Control level? You have created a custom permission level for group 2, right? This custom permission level was copied from "Contribute" level but without "delete" permission checked? This list has check-in/check-out/publish and approval enabled? **PS:**
I think i got it. When you create a workflow, you can check it for "Require the Man

Answer (score 1):

Why Dont you use Event Receiver feature instead of Workflow, I mean you can create a event receiver so that when a new item is added to the list, send email to groups/users you want, you can directly access Active Directory to get groups and then Users.

[tutorial on Item adding feature](http://www.fsmpi.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/getting-started-with-custom-sharepoint-event-receivers/161.html)

[get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net)

Comment: we are 2 SAP guys who temporarily maintain the Sharepoint Server cuz the 2 guys who did it left and the recruiting is still going on. We pretty much took a crashcourse in using SPD and the webinterface to edit stuff. Both of us don`t know VB or C# so we pretty much only stuck to SPD